# "service networking restart" takes ages to complete when using wifi interface

Tags: debian, networking, wifi

I am using latest stable Debian build and trying to follow this [tutorial](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUsetutorial).

Whenever my `/etc/network/interfaces` has anything wifi related, currently:

```
auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
    iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid myrealssid
    wpa-psk sonelongpassphrasereturnedbywpa_passphrase
```

, `service networking restart` quietly takes more than few minutes to complete, without output or success.

`iwlist scan` shows real wifi access points so the device seems to be working.

How do I go about troubleshooting?

Comment: What does `service networking status` say?

Comment: Sorry - already fixed the issue. I think the service was not running after few minutes of idling. Whenever I commented out wireless part of `interfaces`, and used ethernet instead, `networking restart` behaved as expected. Installing/uninstalling `wicd` resolved the problem for me; not sure what the root cause was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone finds this useful.

`ifup wlan0` was more informative and resulted in `No DHCPOFFERS recieved.`

Some people reported that installing `network-manager` or `wicd` once helps,

This resolved the issue for me:

- Installed `wicd` and dependencies,
- Connected to the wireless network via `wicd` (not sure if this was required)
- Uninstalled all packages installed in the step 1
- Now the tutorial in op post works

Obviously this is a bit "dirty" solution.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I see this issue (usually on servers not on wifi) I just do a quick reboot which yields better results.

You'll also see it fail or [OK] upon boot